# Get old revision contents following renames

Tags: git

You can get the contents of a file's previous revision easily with:
`git show <revision>:<path>`

But this fails if `<path>` didn't exist at `<revision>`, this is, if the file was renamed in between.

Is there some way to repeat the first query, but instructing git to follow back renames, so that it shows me the contents at `<revision>` of what is now called `<path>`, whatever was it called then?

Answer (score 1):

The rename tracking works based on heuristics, so you should follow history of the file and find out "most probable" file name. Use `-M` or `-C` or related keys of `git log`. After you find out old file name, you could lookup it using `show`.

Comment: Well, that's what I am currently doing (using `git log --summary <path>` to find out old name, and then using `git show`. But I resist to think there's no better way to do this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @elmart I doubt it has anything like that out-of-box. The `show` just shows objects. And looking for an object inside `<revision>` it has only access to this particular object. And you could have multiple branches coming out of this revision with different histories of the file. It is quite weird if it would work magically to back into future... So, while you using `log` it goes into past and shows all possible renames.

Comment: I understand. But I don't think it's such a weird use case. I mean, you get a list of commits with `git log --follow <path>`, you locate the one you want to look at, but you don't know if the file has gone 3 or 4 renames in between. So, something like `git show --follow <revision>:<path>` would in fact be the natural thing. The same way log traverses back rename info, could be done by `show`, when requesting a path.

Comment: No magic needed, as when we ask something involving the future of <revision>, we ask it... from the future, which is already present, and thus, known. Sorry, I couldn't resist. Marty McFly was pushing me... ;-)

Comment: @elmart When you do `log` you start from HEAD and follow history graph backwards by commit parent links. But you you do `show revision` it starts from the revision and doesn't know what happened in future as it should follow graph in opposite direction, you could do it with DAG.

Comment: @elmart So, yes, technically it's possible, but not using a single command and the macro should accept at least two parameters - revision to start from (HEAD by default) and a target revision which you are looking for a file. Probably you could make an alias or a shell script to simplify it.

Comment: I understand the way it works (starting from `<revision>`). I was just trying to justify that it *could* work differently (at least at a porcelain level). Thanks for your time. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: @elmart Not really understand how _exactly_ it could work. You cannot follow a DAG in the opposite direction. You should start from some refs and follow parents. It doesn't make sense to look all plausible commits, and makes little sense in DVCS. As analogy you could imagine classical single linked list and try to follow in a opposite direction.

Comment: I really think we are saying the same thing. I've already said I understand it can't be done starting from `<revision>`. But nothing prevents the porcelain command to detect the use case we are discussing and then starting from HEAD backwards until `<revision>`, as you are also saying.